# Set directly data members in scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm building a large CSR sparse matrix which uses quite some memory even in sparse format so I want to avoid a copy when I create the matrix. The most efficient way I found is building directly the compressed sparse row representation. However, the class initializer copies the arrays I pass to it, so I have set directly the data members. Example:

```
from scipy import sparse
m = sparse.csr_matrix((5,5))
m.data = np.arange(5)
m.indices = np.arange(5)
m.indptr = np.arange(6)
```

This appears to work but I didn't find it in the documentation, I'd like to know if it is supported, if it breaks something I have not tried.

Also, it would be useful to know if I can use memmapped arrays without quirks, or use different integer datatypes for the indices.

**Edit:**

The accepted answer shows that no copy happens provided the indices types are correct. I have checked the `__init__` and, even when it doesn't copy `indices` and `indptr`, it does scan two times both of them to find the minimum and maximum values, and it effectively does nothing more than setting the `data`, `indices` and `indptr` members if the inputs are well-formed, so for performance what I'm doing now is:

```py
# [...] get shape and data from somewhere
m = sparse.csr_matrix(shape, dtype=data.dtype)
indices = np.empty(..., dtype=m.indices.dtype)
indptr = np.empty(..., dtype=m.indptr.dtype)
# [...] fill indices and indptr
m.data = data
m.indices = indices
m.indptr = indptr
# Possibly also do one or both of the following:
m.has_sorted_indices = True
m.has_canonical_format = True
```

Comment: The relevant `__init__` is `_cs_matrix` in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.4.1/scipy/sparse/compressed.py.  It's the `len(arg1) == 3` case when you pass `data`,`indices`,`indptr` directly.  It doesn't make copies if the `dtypes` are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of making a sparse matrix without copying the definition arrays:

```
In [191]: data=np.arange(5) 
     ...: indices=np.arange(5).astype('int32') 
     ...: indptr=np.arange(6).astype('int32')                                                  
In [192]: M = sparse.csr_matrix((data,indices,indptr))                                         
In [193]: data.__array_interface__['data'], M.data.__array_interface__['data']                 
Out[193]: ((55897168, False), (55897168, False))
In [194]: indices.__array_interface__['data'], M.indices.__array_interface__['data']           
Out[194]: ((70189040, False), (70189040, False))
In [195]: indptr.__array_interface__['data'], M.indptr.__array_interface__['data']             
Out[195]: ((56184432, False), (56184432, False))
```

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.4.1/scipy/sparse/compressed.py

I wrote that with the `__init__` in mind.  Look also at the `check_format` method to see what it checks for consistency.